# Does taking a deep breath reduce the experience of stress and negative emotions?

Tags: emotion, physiology, stress, mood

Sometimes when I have negative feelings, it seems that a deep breath resets these feelings. Does that really happen? Is there any research on the effect of taking a deep breath on reducing the experience of negative emotions?

Comment: Its a ritual and a coping mech. yeah its psychologically identified.

Comment: if those kinds of breathing techniques help you would prolly respond well to mediation as well. you can do a non-religious form which will increase mindfulness

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness_(psychology)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup; basically, it works. [Varvogli and Darviri <sup>(2011)</sup>](http://www.hsj.gr/volume5/issue2/521.pdf) review research on diaphragmatic breathing, reporting:

> **Deep breathing** has been successfully used to decrease the **fatigue** associated with haemopoietic stem cell transplantation patients <sup>55</sup>, to reduce the **anxiety** and asthma signs/symptoms of children with asthma <sup>56</sup>, in the management of **acute stressful** tasks <sup>57</sup> showing that the slow-breathing technique can have a significant effect on improvement of the hemodynamic changes following the **acute stressful** tasks. Furthermore, it has been used to influence autonomic functions in patients with essential hypertension and thus reduce it <sup>58–59</sup>, in the management of male adolescent **aggressive** behaviour <sup>60</sup>, in long term prophylaxis of migraine <sup>61</sup>, in **stress** related to dental visits <sup>62</sup>.

Fatigue, anxiety, stress, and aggression are all negatively valent (see [the diagram in this answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/5337/4086); aggression doesn't appear, but is a form of negative arousal). It wouldn't be surprising if effects on hypertension and migraine incidence are partially mediated by emotional changes either.

<sub>**References**

Varvogli, L., & Darviri, C. (2011). Stress management techniques: Evidence-based procedures that reduce stress and promote health. *Health Science Journal, 5*(2), 74–89. Retrieved from http://www.hsj.gr/volume5/issue2/521.pdf.</sub>

- <sub>As cited within Varvogli & Darviri (2011):</sub>

  <sub>$55$. Sang-Dol, K., & Hee-Seung, K. (2005). Effects of a relaxation breathing exercise on fatigue in haemopoietic stem cell transplantation patients. *Journal of Clinical Nursing, 14*(1), 51–55.

  $56$. Chiang, L. C., Ma, W. F., Huang, J. L., Tseng, L. F., & Hsueh, K. C. (2009) Effect of relaxation-breathing training on anxiety and asthma signs/symptoms of children with moderate-to-severe asthma: A randomized controlled trial. *International Journal of Nursing Studies, 46*(8), 1061–1070. Retrieved from [ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24043294_Effect_of_relaxation-breathing_training_on_anxiety_and_asthma_signssymptoms_of_children_with_moderate-to-severe_asthma_a_randomized_controlled_trial/file/60b7d52a52b71eff5e.pdf).

  $57$. Nogawa, M., Yamakoshi, T., Ikarashi, A., Tanaka, S., & Yamakoshi, K. (2007). Assessment of slow-breathing relaxation technique in acute stressful tasks using a multipurpose non-invasive beat-by-beat cardiovascular monitoring system. *Conf Proc IEEE Eng Med Biol Soc*, 5323–5325.

  $58$. Mourya, M., Mahajan, A. S., Singh, N. P., & Jain, A. K. (2009). Effect of slow- and fast-breathing exercises on autonomic functions in patients with essential hypertension. *Journal of Alternative and Complementary Medicine, 15*(7), 711–717.

  $59$. Kaushik, R. M., Kaushik, R., Mahajan, S. K., & Rajesh, V. (2006). Effects of mental relaxation and slow breathing in essential hypertension. *Complementary Therapies in Medicine, 14*(2), 120–126.

  $60$. Gaines, T., & Barry, L. M. (2008). The effect of a self-monitored relaxation breathing exercise on male adolescent aggressive behavior. *Adolescence, 43*(170), 291–302.

  $61$. Kaushik, R., Kaushik, R. M., Mahajan, S, K., & Rajesh, V. (2005). Biofeedback assisted diaphragmatic breathing and systematic relaxation versus propranolol in long term prophylaxis of migraine. *Complementary Therapies in Medicine, 13*(3), 165–174.

  $62$. Biggs, Q. M., Kelly, K. S., & Toney J. D. (2003). The effects of deep diaphragmatic breathing and focused attention on dental anxiety in a private practice setting. *Journal of Dental Hygiene, 77*(2), 105–113.</sub>

Comment: Nick. You probably don't know but these answers full of references are breathtaking. I guess I'm in love with you. :3

Comment: "Breathtaking" eh? I see what you did there! :D I'll have to check out your other questions and see if I can capitalize on your high regard for me ;) Don't give me too much credit on this one though! Varvogli & Darviri (2011) was one of the first Google hits for something like "deep breathing negative emotion research", and I really just copied and checked references from their article, since it happened to include a decent review already (the quoted section above).

Comment: Yes. But it would be kinda hard for me to search. I'm not from cognitive sciences, but I do have interest in some things. I believe that my vocabulary for searching it in my native languange is poor, but it should be much worse in english. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting that you should've found this stuff on your own, just that I didn't do anything too amazing for this answer :) But do give it a shot whenever you have a question! You'd be amazed at how easy it is to find useful research sometimes! Especially by searching with the word "research" ;) Feel free to ask me for help in choosing keywords too if you don't have full-fledged questions to ask here...and clearly no harm done in asking this one. It's pretty popular already!

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer is very thorough. I would add that the physiological symptoms of high-stress (muscle tightening, accelerated heartbeat, shallow quick breath) can be reversed by controlling breath voluntarily. So, when you change these physical conditions, emotional state often follows.